# Is overflow:hidden the correct way to make sure floated items don't "leak"?

Tags: html, css

Say you have a list of articles, some have a right floated image and very little text, so the image floats outside the article and into the next article, messing things up.

What is the correct/preferred/best way to make sure the elements inside the article does not float outside of it?

I know that `overflow:hidden` works, but is this correct usage? Or does it just happen to do what I want out of chance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three ways to do it:

1. you can have `overflow:hidden` which is a clean way to do it.

   - Pros: It does not mess with semantics of the HTML, No "dead elements".
   - Cons: clipping the content if the container has a defined dimension, *and clips shadows* from inner elements.

     ```
     div        <-- style="overflow:hidden"
         div    <-- floating children
         div    
     div        <-- style="overflow:hidden"
         div    <-- floating children
         div
     ```
2. You can have a blank element, usually a `<div>` after the container that has floats. Style this with `clear:both`.

   - Cons: Having a "dead element" in the DOM.

     ```
     div
         div    <-- floating children
         div 
     div        <-- style="clear:both"
     div 
         div    <-- floating children
         div
     ```
3. You can add a "clearfix" class to the container and use `:after` pseudo-class to add a "clearing dynamic dot/space". Basically it works like the second, but uses the `:after` to insert a space that has "clear:both" [This article explains it](http://perishablepress.com/new-clearfix-hack/).

   - Pros: It does not mess with semantics of the HTML, No "dead elements".
   - Cons: "classitis" (overuse of classes), [`:after` is not supported in IE7](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) and older, thus CSS hacks are used

     ```
     div        <-- :after
         div    <-- floating children
         div
     " "        <-- style="clear:both"
     div        <-- :after
         div    <-- floating children
         div
     ```

You can use either of the three and they work great. I usually use 1 most of the time, and if I had shadows in the container, or if the container has a fixed dimension, I use 3. Method 3 relies on `:after` which is new. To support this clearfix, youd use an old CSS hack as described in the article.

Comment: Nice summary, you missed the obvious though: simply putting a clear on the direct descendant. works in many cases but is often overlooked.

Comment: My problem with using clear is that it messes with my sidebar :/ Guess I'll stick with overflow:hidden in this case.

Answer (score 2):

For each article element, add `clear: both;`. This will ensure that images don't "leak" on the next article, but also makes sure they're not cut-off.

Comment: Problem with this is that the articles messes with the sidebar which is also floated.

Comment: Then in your particular case, `overflow: hidden` is OK because of the sidebar. Please post some HTML/CSS if you're in a particular case.

Answer (score 1):

[This link explains exactly what you asked.](http://www.impressivewebs.com/overflow-hidden-problem/)

overflow: hidden or overflow: auto would be acceptable solutions for clearing floats on smaller containing elements like a navigation bar that holds floated list items, or a call-to-action area that has a bunch of floated boxes.

And the link also explains the problem of using overflow:hidden to clear with a demo.